# Unable to open D drive files, of File type, in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I am unable to open a "File" type file in python.
This file exists in D drive.

```
f = os.path.join('D:\Udacity Datasets', 'maildir/bailey-s/deleted_items/101')
g=open(f) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\Udacity Datasets\\maildir/bailey-s/deleted_items/101'
```

However, if the same file is in C drive, it works fine

```
f = os.path.join('C:\Users\shivanand\Documents\Udacity\Data Analyst  Nanodegree\P5 - Intro to ML\ud120-projects-master', 'maildir/bailey-s/deleted_items/101' )
g = open(f)
```

I have also observed that 'txt' files can be read from D drives, 
i.e

```
f = os.path.join('D:\Udacity Datasets', 'maildir/bailey-s/test.txt')
g = open(f)
```

works well, but throws an error for 'File' type files.

Could someone kindly point out the error

Comment: Execute `dir "D:\Udacity Datasets\maildir\bailey-s\deleted_items"` in Windows' shell and include output in your question to prove that `101` file indeed exists in filesystem.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski yes, it does exist (also checked via your cmd), in fact as I mentioned above, if I put the same file in C directory and execute the command, everything works just fine.

Comment: Why exactly won't you include command and output in question to prove to us it's not another 'oops, misspelled path' question?

Comment: Does `g=open(os.path.normpath(f))` helps?

Answer (score 0):

f = os.path.join('D:\Udacity Datasets', **'maildir/bailey-s/deleted_items/101'**)

You have wrong slash in highlighted part. It should be **'maildir\bailey-s\deleted_items\101'**

Comment: It is giving the same error

>>> f = os.path.join('D:\Udacity Datasets', 'maildir/bailey-s/deleted_items/101')
>>> g = open(f)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\Udacity Datasets\\maildir/bailey-s/deleted_items/101'

Comment: @ShivanandT and you still have wrong slashes, you use \ at the first argument of `join` and / at the second argument. You should always use \ in windows.

Comment: I am still getting the same error I tried >>>f = os.path.join('D:/Udacity Datasets/', 'maildir/bailey-s/deleted_items/101') 
I also tried >>>f = os.path.join('D:/Udacity Datasets', 'maildir/bailey-s/deleted_items/101'). Perhaps the issue is not in the slashing as everything works well If I read a txt file >>> f = os.path.join('D:\Udacity Datasets', 'maildir/bailey-s/deleted_items/test.txt') works fine